# Why are (-) marks showing up in my editor in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I was writing some code and I don't know what I did, but my code started looking like this. I'm using boot camp on a mac and I tried to type the `{` like you do on a mac, and I think I hit a hot key.

The `-` marks are kinda greenish and ignored by the compiler.

```
if (someThing == 10)
{
----(if someOtherThing != 20)
----{

--------DoSomething();

----}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned on "Show Whitespace" - [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/09/view-white-space-vstipedit0043.aspx)

The keyboard shortcut you accidentally hit to to enable it is `CTRL + R, CTRL + W`.

Comment: Thanks, CTRL + W did the job

Answer (score 1):

You've turned on "Show Whitespace" - you can toggle this in the menus, under:
**Edit** > **Advanced** > **Show Whitespce**